# Reactjs Debounce search field re-renders component if the field is not empty

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a debounce search and initially when the field is empty the component renders after the provided setTimeout delay. But if I continue to search with the existing keyword it re-renders the List component on each key stroke. How to avoid that?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import useDebounce from './hooks/useDebounce';
import List from './components/List';

const App: React.FC = () => {
    const [todo, setTodo] = useState<string>("");
    const [query, setQuery] = useState<string | null>("");
    let deBounceSearch = useDebounce(query, 2000);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (deBounceSearch) {
            console.log('Searching...');
        } else {
            console.log('...');
        }       
    }, [deBounceSearch]);

    return (
        <div className="App">   
            <input type="text" placeholder='Search anything' onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)} />
            {deBounceSearch !== '' && (
                <List />
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

useDebounce.tsx

```
const useDebounce = (value: any, delay: number) => {
    const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(value);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handler = setTimeout(() => { setDebouncedValue(value) }, delay);
        return () => {
            clearTimeout(handler);
        }
    }, [value, delay]);

    return debouncedValue;
}    
export default useDebounce;
```

Comment: Did you tried to use `useMemo` to cache the List?

Comment: Nope...can u provide that with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [useMemo](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useMemo) to avoid re-render the `List` component every time `query` value changes:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
    const [todo, setTodo] = useState<string>("");
    const [query, setQuery] = useState<string | null>("");
    const deBounceSearch = useDebounce(query, 2000);
    // -> 
    const cachedList = React.useMemo(() => <List />, [debouncedValue]);

    ...

    return (
        <div className="App">   
            <input type="text" placeholder='Search anything' onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)} />
            {deBounceSearch !== '' && cachedList}
        </div>
    );
}
```

You also can take a look at `React.memo`

Answer (score 0):

hello man this is not the best to use debounce i suggest u try `lodash` debounce with `useMemo`.

but for now the solution for your code is that you forgot to clear the timeout on every time the value change.
here the solution:

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const useDebounce = (value, delay) => {
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(value);
  const handler = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (handler.current) {
      clearTimeout(handler.current);
    }
    handler.current = setTimeout(() => {
      setDebouncedValue(value);
    }, delay);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(handler.current);
    };
  }, [value, delay]);

  return debouncedValue;
};

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const debounceSearch = useDebounce(value, 2000);

  console.log(debounceSearch);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

hope this help .